# oData, Yii2, and Dynamic Objects

Tags: rest, yii2, odata, api-design

We have a system built on dynamic objects - so there is a metadata table that describes these objects. For example - Organization A can have a Warehouse Object, a Client Object and a Sales Object. Organization B can have a Sales Object and a Clown Object.

Users authenticate to our rest api built on the Yii2 framework. They authenticate using a call to /user/authenticate and then they query for objects using /object/ for list / create and /object// for Read, Update, Delete.

The issue with this is: If a developer is going to integrate into the service, they would need to know all objects that have been defined in their organization including available fields they are able to read/write to. What we would like to do is provide an option to describe our data.

E.g. My initial thought would be to expose something like /object/metadata in which I would respond with a json list of resources that the user is allowed to access e.g. a Warehouse A user would see Warehouse, Client, Sale. Where a Org B user would see Sales, Clown.

I have been asked to take a look at oData as a specification for this but oData seems to define a whole convention of things (url, searching and filtering etc).

Does it make sense to implement part of the oData Spec or use it as a guide and keep our URLs the same? 
Is there a part of the oData spec that would lend itself to the describing of a dynamic resource (e.g. if the user uses our system to add a column to the Sales object - the api should reflect that).

Would appreciate any thoughts on how to design / proceed with this requirement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I created follow solution:

- extend dektrium/yii2-rbac, where to assigments add column company
- in each module (werhause, invoices,..) created roles objects
- roles object has methods: canAssign(), canView(), canRemove() for user administartion
- user administration panel collect all roles from all modules (scan as files) and display grouped by modules.

This solution allow to user switching between companies and for users assign different access rights to different companies and control user manager rights assigning rights[image]

Comment: We have already implemented a RBAC system. The question was in regards to using oData specification to describe a REST api

Comment: For entity use odata.editLink and odata.readLink. if no defined odata.editLink - entity can not edit.
For fields add own odata.editablefileds.

Comment: we have decided to roll our own descriptors - is odata.editablefields documented?

Comment: Yes, creating odata.editablefields is right solution